# getting error : Could not proxy request /api/plaid/accounts from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

My app is working on localhost:3000, I need to call plaid API call for that I am using `axios`, when it runs the `plaid API` call it is giving me error `Could not proxy request /api/plaid/accounts from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/`, I am strange why it goes to `http://localhost:5000/` ? and why I am getting this error ? can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you please provide, the code which is giving error

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. Please, try to update react-scripts with `sudo npm install--save react-scripts`, in the actual stable version that problem is fixed.